# How to call/echo php function on 2nd php page

Tags: php, echo, call

i want to create a process.php function where i want that php generate random number, and i want that these numbers should be shown in 2nd page. i don't know how to call this function on 2nd page because i am newbie in php. 
Here is my code which i am trying to implement.

```
mt_srand(mktime());
echo(mt_rand());
```

These random numbers generated by php should be shown on 2nd page i.e final.php when applying echo function  like this:
`04572579`
Thanks in advance

Comment: in the second page, you need first to `include` your first page then you can call your function easy as you want

Comment: This is what i was looking for.. thanks a lot Joseph

Comment: mark my answer as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the second page, you need first to `include` your first page then you can call your function easy as you want

Comment: now i have one more problem, i want that 2nd page should show only the result of 1st page. like i am using the command  echo generatePassword(); in the 1st page, how can i call this on 2nd page so that 2nd page should show me the same characters even if i refresh 2nd page?

Comment: you can save the value you want in session from the first page then you can print it in the second

Comment: i really don't know how to save the value in session, would you please guide me how to do this??

Comment: in <form> method, i use this command to call it on 2nd page <?php echo $_POST["password"]; ?> but i don't know how to do this on this type of php method

Comment: in the first page first open session `session_start()` then save it in session `$_SESSION['number'] = 'your data here'` at last print it out in the second page